# 401 Unauthorized using Jquery Ajax even after providing Authorization

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, cross-browser, http-status-code-401

I am trying to make a Jquery Ajax call as shown below -

```
$.support.cors = true;
var lookupReq = $.ajax({url:link, async:false, type: "GET", beforeSend : function(req) { 
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth); 
} });
```

I have checked auth value and it is correct. I have checked the Header request info in Fiddler and am getting the correct Authorization info there -

```
Authorization Header is present: Basic RFQ3MzYwNjpEc3R3c0A0NTY=
Decoded Username:Password= DT73606:Dstws@456
```

But I am still getting 401 Unauthorized error in Fiddler response -

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="AWD"
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 Feb 2015 07:15:57 GMT

10
Session expired.
0
```

This request is working fine and giving HTTP 200 OK when I am trying from mozilla and RestClient by passing the username and pwd.
**What is wrong here??? Please Help.**

**EDIT**

To my surprise Restclient is error prone. Even if I give wrong Basic authorization value, it is responding with HTTP 200 OK.

Yesterday I got a very interesting scenario -

When I am calling the link from IE after cleaning up its history and cache, it is asking for username and pwd and after submitting the correct credentials, it is responding with HTTP 200 OK (displaying the image). But it is giving error when we are trying from our code. Now this code contains a lot of other calls also prior to this call. Moreover this call (link) triggers some authentication (which checks for cookies containg JSESSIONID and if not present it takes the Authorization details to validate and if successful, creates a new JSESSIONID and passes it to make further calls).
I suspect that in our code, as we are making other calls and when we are making this link call it looks for JSESSIONID and it is found (that's why even after repeated try to provide Login detals it is still showing 401 error).
Now, we need to make sure that this link call takes the correct JSESSIONID otherwise accept the login details as provided.

**Any kind of suggestion is welcome.**

Comment: Are you sure that the server accepts the authentication scheme 'basic' as opposed to, say, 'digest' ?

Comment: @collapsar Yes, the server accepts 'basic'. I confirmed it in RestClient.